# show whole database data tkinter sqlite3

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to print history that's in a database on a window but my program only shows two lines (not even ordered). what's the problem?
when printing it I get the data correctly but I can't get them on the window.
for me it makes no sense.

```
                def his(self, database, progx):

                    con = sqlite3.connect(database)
                    with con:
                        cur = con.cursor()
                        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + progx + ' ORDER BY id DESC ')
                        index=3
                        for row in cur.fetchall():
                            print(row) #this works just fine
                            Label(self, text=row[1]).grid(row=index, column=0)
                            Label(self, text=row[2]).grid(row=index, column=1)
                            Label(self, text=row[3]).grid(row=index, column=2)
                            Label(self, text=row[4]).grid(row=index, column=3)
                            Label(self, text=row[5]).grid(row=index, column=4)
                            Label(self, text=row[6]).grid(row=index, column=5)
                            Label(self, text=row[7]).grid(row=index, column=6)
                            Label(self, text=row[8]).grid(row=index, column=7)
                            Label(self, text=row[9]).grid(row=index, column=8)
                            Label(self, text=row[10]).grid(row=index, column=9)
                            Label(self, text=row[11]).grid(row=index, column=10)
                            Label(self, text=row[12]).grid(row=index, column=11)
                            Label(self, text=row[13]).grid(row=index, column=12)
                            Label(self, text=row[14]).grid(row=index, column=13)
                            hist.update()
                            index=+1
```

Comment: `for n in range(14): Label(self, text=row[n+1]).grid(row=index, column=n)` will get rid of all that ugly repetitive code

Comment: thanks but that does't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just a little tip for future use. To me, it looks like the problem must be caused by something else in your code. If the data printed out looks fine, I see no reason why that shouldn't work.

Comment: please create a [mcve], preferably one that doesn't rely on an external database. For example, you could simulate your data with a predefined list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not iterating through widgets properly because indexing is wrong.
Change:

```
index=+1
```

To:

```
index += 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this since yesterday.